# how to import custom .d.ts files from tsconfig

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a monorepo and several typescript projects.  I have a tsconfig.base.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es5", "es6"],
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  }
}
```

I then have a derived tsconfig.json in each subproject.

I have my own custom type definitions and one of each is for `universal-cookie.ts` that I store in a folder 2 levels up from the derived `tsconfig.json`

In my types folder I have a `universal-cookie.d.ts` file but I cannot get the typescript compiler to pick up the types in this folder.

My derived tsconfig.json looks like this

```
{
  "extends": "../../common/frontend-common/typescript/tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es5", "es6"]
  },
  "files": ["../../types/*"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "../../types/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "src/**/*.test.tsx", "src/**/*.test.ts", "src/test/**/*", "src/features/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: which package manager?